# Can't login to sql server custom db

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, php, wamp

I have wamp installed in my system and sql server 2014, and configure so i can access sql server db through php.. with this code:

```
<?php 
$serverName = "MY-PC\sqlexpress"; 

$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"master");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

that actually works. But when i change "master" with some "customdb" its giving me this error.

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38. Login failed for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.  Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified
>   database 'customdb'. [CLIENT: ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't added to service account as a database user to customdb:

```
USE customdb;
CREATE USER [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM];
```

You will also need to grant the needed permissions on database objects to allow a minimally privileged user to access data.  I suggest you do this via role membership to facilitate manageability:

```
USE customdb;
CREATE ROLE YourRole;
ALTER ROLE YourRole ADD MEMBER [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM];
GRANT SELECT ON YourTable TO YourRole;
```

These symptoms may also be due to the account name and SID beging different, perhaps because the database was restored/attached. Try dropping and recreating the login and user.

Comment: I added NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM as database user and give it all roles possible, and still the same problem, its so irritating..
master db doesn't have NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM as user but its working

Comment: Are you certain you are connecting to the intended SQL Server instance?  Check the SQL Server error log as that should contain this error and perhaps more details.

Comment: here is 2 prictures with my object explorer in SSMS and the error log file from sqlexpress
[link](http://imgur.com/a/PjI8n)

Comment: It may be that the account name and SID are different, perhaps because the database was restored or attached.  Try dropping and recreating the login and user.

Comment: Man thank you, you save my life i have search the net for 3 days now and finaly is working.. i wanna kiss you